# IntelliJ: .class file outputs to src folder of submodule instead of project out folder when compiled via command line

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm an IntelliJ noob.

I have a module with submodules, which contain submodules as well. When compiling class files from any submodule within IntelliJ, it outputs the .class file to the corresponding out folder of the parent module (as desired):

When compiled via "run" button in IntelliJ:
[When compiled via IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDONg.png)

However, when compiling the same file via the command line, the class files are generated within the src folder for that module:

.class file outputs to src folder of submodule instead of project out folder when compiled via command line.
[When compiled via command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4ZeG.png)

How can I get the java files compiled via command line to output to the same out folder as they do when compiled via intellij?

Thanks for any ideas.

I tried setting the dependencies of Lecture7... and LectureCode modules to DataStructures module and have the compiler output path to "inherit project compile output path" under module settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to "File" -> "Project Structure" -> "Modules".
2. Select your module.
3. Select Paths.
4. There you have the configure the output path for your source code and tests.

Comment: Hi Rico, thanks for the suggestion. But, like I said, I have already have the compiler output path configured to "inherit project compile output path" under module settings, which produces the class file in the project's out folder (as desired). The problem is when the compiling the same file via the command line, the .class file is still being placed within the module's src folder despite the output path being set to the project's out folder.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Then what you have it's not a IntelliJ problem, you have a java compilation problem. What command are you using to compile?

Comment: No problem. I'm using "javac SpeetTestAList.java" from within the src folder. I assumed I had to be in the source folder to run that command but maybe that's the source of the problem? I'm just not sure how to compile it from the command line in any other way.

Comment: You are not especifying the output directory. Use instead `javac -d <directory-path><source-files>`. I recommend you to read the documentation for javac.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for your help and the reference to the documentation, which I'll consult if I have any trouble in the future.